# How are logs ordered by the dumpio (mod_dumpio) module in Apache? (Logs identifiers)

Tags: apache, logging, dump

Guess that Apache received two POST requests at a same time. They would be normally logged by the dumpio module in the correct order like below. Where you can see that log 3 belongs to POST logged in the post 1 (/mypage_1/) and log 4 belongs to the post logged in log 2 (/mypage_2/).

1. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **POST /mypage_1/** HTTP/1.1\r\n
2. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **POST /mypage_2/** HTTP/1.1\r\n
3. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **xml_request=I_Belong_To_mypage_1**
4. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c(74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **xml_request=I_Belong_To_mypage_2**

I wonder if by any chance they could be logged in a different order like below. And in this case I would not know what request belongs to what POST. **Is there any way for me to know the requests that belong to each POST?**

1. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c (74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **POST /mypage_1/** HTTP/1.1\r\n
2. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c (74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **POST /mypage_2/** HTTP/1.1\r\n
3. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c (74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **xml_request=I_Belong_To_mypage_2**
4. [Thu Dec 13 11:28:01 2012] [debug] mod_dumpio.c (74): mod_dumpio:
   dumpio_in (data-HEAP): **xml_request=I_Belong_To_mypage_1**